# HTTP and HTTPS iptables rule is getting ignored

Tags: http, https, iptables

I already know that the answer with be something simple that I have messed up with! But any idea what's going wrong with these rules?

`sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -m multiport --dports http,https -j ACCEPT`

`sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -m multiport --sports http,https -j ACCEPT`

I have the DNS set up and every packet for this is arriving to my server so this isn't the problem.

Thanks in advance,
Luke

Comment: What are you expecting these rules to do?

Comment: Sorry just noticed I had DROP as the action, I was testing these rules using that just before I posted. The rules should (I will change them now) accept any HTTP or HTTPS packet that comes in. However, the rule is getting ignored and the default deny is always considered.

Comment: What are you expecting these rules to do? (Are these inbound HTTP connections to a local web server that you're trying to allow? Are these outbound connections to other web servers?)

Comment: They are for a firewall at the router of an organisation. I have a mail server and web server along with some workstations that also use the same firewall. So it's really for a local web server and for outbound traffic to web servers.

Comment: Are these the rules for the interface facing inward, outward, or both? Is this machine doing NAT?

Comment: It's for both the inward and outward interface.

Comment: Then where's the rule when the first packet is *inbound* and the *source* port is the http port?

Comment: I am currently setting it all up on one virtual machine first. So it just goes to http (80) or https (443)... or so I believed.

Answer (score 0):

Think about a NATted outbound connection to a remote web server. The first packet in the flow between the NAT and the remote web server will be an *outbound* packet with a *destination* port of 80. You have no rule that packet would match.